# Django Forms with ReactJS

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have Django forms rendered using Django templates. Now I want to add a React component to one of the form fields (and perhaps to more than one field in the long term).

Based on what I have read so far, its seem best not to mix Django templating with React rendering and have Django serve only as backend API sending JSON data to React, while React takes over the entire form rendering. So I am now trying to re-render my forms entirely through React.

Instead of forms.py, I have now created serializers.py to define what data is to be sent to React and have Django Rest Framework setup in my environment. Now I am trying to figure out how to send this data across. There are some good online tutorials (and SO posts) that talk about integrating Django/DRF with React but havent found a single example of end-to-end form rendering through React and DRF.
Specifically, can anyone let me know what do I really write in my view that can then be useful for the GET request from React that tries to fetch the form data? A web reference or just the broad steps needed should be enough for me to get started (and to dig in more into the docs).

Update:
Also adding a simplified version of the serializers.py code here:

```
from .models import Entity
from rest_framework import serializers


class EntitySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = ['name', 'role', 'location']
```

Comment: 1 upvote and 1 down. Would be happy to get downvotes supported by comments please. I have been looking for a good solution to this (and the right way of doing things) but surprisingly could not find even one example of Django forms rendered through React yet. DRF has a good documentation but (if I understand it correctly) I didnt see a good example of form data being sent over yet (i.e user gets a blank form, fills it in, submits it back - all with Django only serving as a back-end API and React rendering on the front end)  which I guess should be a pretty common use case

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, i think you need to check [related React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs) about forms with multiple inputs. It gives you base idea about how things should be structured in React side.

About fetching data from server, you can try something like this in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Assuming you are using jQuery,
    // if not, try fetch().
    // Note that 2 is hardcoded, get your user id from 
    // URL or session or somewhere else.
    $.get('/api/profile/2/', (data) => {
        this.setState({
            formFields: data.fields // fields is an array
        });
    });
}
```

Then you can create your html input elements in `render` method with something like this:

```
render () {
    let fields = this.state.formFields.map((field) => {
        return (
            <input type="text" value={field.value} onChange={(newValue) => {/* update your  state here with new value */ }} name={field.name}/>
        )
    });
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <form action="">
                {fields}
                <button onClick={this.submitForm.bind(this)}>Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And here is your `submitForm` method:

```
submitForm() {
    $.post('/api/profile/2/', {/* put your updated fields' data here */}, (response) => {
       // check if things done successfully.
    });
}
```

**Update:**

Here is an `untested-but-should-work` example for your DRF view:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class ProfileFormView(APIView):
    # Assume you have a model named UserProfile
    # And a serializer for that model named UserSerializer
    # This is the view to let users update their profile info.
    # Like E-Mail, Birth Date etc.

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return UserProfile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except:
            return None

    # this method will be called when your request is GET
    # we will use this to fetch field names and values while creating our form on React side
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        if not user:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 0, 'message': 'User with this id not found'})

        # You have a serializer that you specified which fields should be available in fo
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        # And here we send it those fields to our react component as json
        # Check this json data on React side, parse it, render it as form.
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    # this method will be used when user try to update or save their profile
    # for POST requests.
    def post(self, request, pk, format=None):
        try:
            user = self.get_object(pk)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 0, 'message': 'User with this id not found'})

        e_mail = request.data.get("email", None)
        birth_date = request.data.get('birth_date', None)
        job = request.data.get('job', None)

        user.email = e_mail
        user.birth_date = birth_date
        user.job = job

        try:
            user.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status': 1, 'message': 'Your profile updated successfully!'})
        except:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 0, 'message': 'There was something wrong while updating your profile.'})
```

And this is related url for this view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/profile/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', ProfileFormView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! To get started, I am specifically looking for how to to structure my Django view. I have been trying to follow the example given in the [DRF Tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#writing-regular-django-views-using-our-serializer) but it talks about creating and updating an existing model instance etc.. I want to write an API endpoint in the view that will allow sending form fields to the other side so a blank form can be rendered for the user to fill. It appears to be a very basic use case but I cant find any examples so far.

Comment: Since you are using `react` for creating html part, why do you need `django forms` anymore? You can create empty forms just in react. And to get values (like `ModelForm`), you can use api views + ajax requests.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean not sending the form fields to React to render the form and define the fields on the React side itself? (because that would be a bit non-DRYish since I'll be maintaining the form fields at two separate places?) I am not using Django forms but need a way to send the form fields to React so React knows which fields to render (also updated the question with a simplified version of serializers.py if it helps at all). Thanks for trying to help me out.

Comment: @AnupamJain is this supposed to be a ModelForm or normal form [like a contact-us or login form]?

Comment: Thanks again @alix. Yes, this is a ModelForm that I am trying to convert to DRF+React.

Comment: Really appreciate your persistent follow-up and time, @alix. I guess I just have to edit the `get()` method for the case where the user is filling a blank form to add a new user profile instead of updating an existing one, is it?

Comment: @AnupamJain Yes. if user already exists, just update it. If not, create new one with new data coming from react side as json!

Comment: Thanks!  (and apologies if my questions sound dumb. Just trying to get a hang of things in the Django-React world)

Comment: No worries! Glad to help you :)

Comment: Don't forget to add the CSRF protection to the form [here](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-react-forms-csrf-axios/) are several ways to do that

Comment: Hello, the question is not dumb at all. ModelForms are a quick an easy way to make a form based on the model. The information from the model definition goes to the form so you dont have to tell whether a field is a text input, a selection, etc... with react you have to write this yourself, which is already defined in the model, so it breaks the DRY principle.