# django - modelforms and react - DRY

Tags: django, reactjs, django-forms

I'm adding React to my django web app and I'm not sure how to proceed with forms.

In pure django, you can just render a form with `{{my_form.as_p}}` and this will create inputs for all the fields with the correct input type. If you use `ModelForm`, you don't even need to create a definition for the fields because it will just take it from the django model definition, keeping the DRY principle very nicely.

With React I understand that it's best to give the data as json and let React take care of rendering and not use django template rendering. But with forms, this means that I have to write all the form fields by hand. Not only this is much more effort, but also it is breaking the DRY principle because I have to have two definitions of the same thing in two separate places that I need to keep in sync.

Is there any library/best practice for this? Is there any way to create a json with the form definition as well as the data, and some way to render this in react without having to manually write all the fields?

Comment: Please take a look here [django forms with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297614/django-forms-with-reactjs)

Comment: I've seen that but it doesn't answer the question because it just constructs all fields as text inputs. I don't want to construct the fields by hand because some are text inputs. Some are selects, some are checkboxes... It seems there should be a solution for this already