# React and Django - Connect the Note model with the specific User

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a notes saving app using react and django_rest_framework.

My Note model -

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Note(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Note Serializer -

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Note

class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ("id", "title", "content")
```

For register and logging in I am following the answer here - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68403179/serve-django-views-with-react)

My react code to store a note -

```
const requestOptions = {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
       body: JSON.stringify({ title: this.state.title, content: this.state.note })
     };
     await fetch('http://localhost:8000/notes/', requestOptions);
```

Now, how do I connect my note object to the specific logged in user so a particular note is only visible to that user?

This can be done with ForeignKey in django but how to do it in django_rest_framework?

**EDIT 1**

I followed the answer given by @Abhyudai but I am getting this error -

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: notes_note.user_id
```

**EDIT 2**

views.py -

```
from .serializers import NoteSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Note
from rest_framework import status

class NoteView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        notes = Note.objects.all()
        serializer = NoteSerializer(notes, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: could you show the `NoteSerializer` **views.py**.

Comment: @AliAref Added views.py

Answer (score 0):

You probably will have to add a field `user` on the `Note` `model`.

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Note(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

...
```

And then inside your `serializer`:

```py
# serializers.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Note

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = get_user_model()
       fields = ('id', 'username')
       lookup_field = 'username'

class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ("id", "title", "content")
```

You may read more at [`serializing` nested objects](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects).

As your application grows, you probably would want to move the `UserSerializer` to an `auth` or `users` app.

You will have to create a `permission` to ensure that only the user who created the note can view the note.

This is one of the ways of doing it.

```py
# permissions.py
fromr rest_framework import permissions


class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
      if request.user: # note: this will prevent an unnecessary database query in case of unauthenticated user  
          return obj.user == request.user
```

You may read more at [`permissions`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#permissions).

For views, you may use something similar to the one used below.

```py
# views.py
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from .models import Note
from .serializers import NoteSerializer
from .permissions import IsOwner

class ListNoteView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Note.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer
    permissions = (IsOwner,)
```

You may read more at [`generics views`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview).

Comment: I am getting an error. Please see the updated question for details.

Comment: You're probably trying to access the view without logging in a user. Use permissions [`is_authenticated`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated) on the `view`.

Comment: Ok, so how do I store it in django that the user has logged in?

Comment: I have added `views` to the answer. I think this should do it for you.

Comment: But when I am logging in, django's not keeping me logged in so I can't access it

Comment: what do you mean by not keeping me logged in?

Comment: That when I login using the LoginAPI and then access the view with the IsAuthenticated permission, I am not able to access it. It is 403 FORBIDDEN.

Comment: what is the LoginAPI that you're tallking about? Also, I think you probably will have to add the permission other than the default authenticated permission for this. I have updated my answer for the new permissions.